# Honda cbr250r ECU question

Tags: engine, honda, motorcycle, electronic-control-module, cbr250r

Can a used ECU from a Honda CBR250R be reprogrammed with different

parameters to increase performance?

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to improve performance go with a piggyback system that controls both fuelling and ignition timing. A piggyback system can be remapped yourself too an unlimited number of times.

A stock ECU remap can potentially damage your engine as it overrides several safety parameters put in place by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually ECUs from factory are not tuned to the highest possible performance figure, but are tuned in balance of power, handling, longevity, maintainability, etc.

It should be possible to reprogram ECUs, but it's much more wise to use plug and play devices(Dynojet, Powertronic to name few), which are altering air/fuel ratio to increase performance, and you are always free to unplug them and get to the factory settings.

Comment: The ECUs are usually programmed to meet various regulatory requirements above all other considerations. I'm not aware of any OEM ECU that is programmable. The aftermarket devices you are listing only "trick" the input parameters to the ECU to change its behavior and do not reprogram it.

Comment: I haven't said that after market devices reprogram ECUs.

Also what you mean, by saying that you can't reprogram OEM ECU? I have software engineering background and as I'm aware of, almost every hardware can be reprogrammed, including ECUs.

Comment: Very well, please link to the tool used for programming the ECU.

Comment: https://rideapart.com/articles/hows-work-ecu-tuning

Comment: I worked for a major after market parts distributor, and our lawyers advised against such technologies because it violates copyright law. Yes, you can do it, but anyone selling the tool is eventually going to get shut down. (Also, at the time I pointed out to the lawyers that it seemed similar to flashing a router, but they said there was something extra the OEMs have that makes this different.)

Comment: Why downvote then?